# What does Round Trip Time / Transmission Time tell us?

Tags: broadcast

To phrase it as it's phrased more commonly:
What does `RTT/T` tell us?

I've seen this formula - Transmission Efficiency - mentioned a lot when it comes to networks:

```
β = RTT/T
```

But what exactly does this mean? Why is it useful? What's the intuition behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transmission time reflects how long it takes for a device to push a packet onto the wire at line rate - it's purely a function of packet size and bit rate.  The round-trip time adds in the speed-of-light delays, queueing delays, etc.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_time, ...Round-trip_delay_time and ...Bandwidth-delay_product